# How to create a banner in wordpress without help of plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am very new to WordPress, and i want to create my own custom banner in WordPress without plugin help. I tried to search many times but can't able to resolve my problem, please anyone help me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use HTML and jquery code .

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't write code for you. Please ask specific questions and show that you have put in effort before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :
Call the below code in your header.php before closing head tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".default .carousel").jCarouselLite({
btnNext: ".default .next",
btnPrev: ".default .prev"
});
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/css/style-demo.css">
//download this css from https://github.com/ganeshmax/jcarousellite and put it in your theme css directory 

<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
//download this js file https://github.com/ganeshmax/jcarousellite here and put it in your theme js directory 
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/jquery.jcarousellite.js"></script>
//download this js file https://github.com/ganeshmax/jcarousellite here and put it in your theme js directory
```

Call below code in your wordpress page with text type content or if you want you can also call it in your wordpress php files too

```
<div id="jcl-demo">
<div class="custom-container default"><a class="prev" href="#">‹</a>
<div class="carousel">
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/image/1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/image/2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/image/1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/image/2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/image/1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/image/2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/image/1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/image/2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/image/1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/image/2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/image/1.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<a class="next" href="#">›</a>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am not looking for jquery.. I want to display manually created banner with the help of php code in wordpress.

Comment: Clear your question first .? This is manually created banner with PHP code you just need to call PHP , CSS and js code into PHP files and HTML code in your dashboard .

Comment: Here is my question., To Develop a plugin in wordpress to manage frontend banners.