# Change Slider from WP-admin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, slider

I have a jQuery slider in my Wordpress website. I want users to change the slider from the WP-admin and not use the code. How can i achieve this? Is there a plugin or i have to make custom plugin? If custom plugin then can i get some ideas?

Comment: Try to be a little more specific. You want users to be able to change the slider or the images inside it ? What is the jQuery slider you already are using ?

Comment: By user i means any other person that logins the wp-admin. I am using a normal jquery slider. all i want is to have a setting option in the wordpress dashboard from which i can change the slider image rather than going to the code and changing the image.

Comment: It still is hard for me to figure what kind of slider you are using now ( fully coded by you or included with theme or ... ? ) but there's a lot of sliders using jQuery available for WordPress. Most of them will allow customization through wp-admin. You can find a list [here](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/tags/jquery-slider)

Comment: I am using my own jquery slider. Thats what i am asking, how can i customize it via wp-admin?

Comment: There is no plugin able to do that as every code is different. If you absolutely want to keep your own jQuery slider, you'll have to make your custom plugin too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387880/how-to-create-a-banner-in-wordpress-without-help-of-plugin/38388606#38388606 please check this link